# How can I subtract the specified date from today's date

Tags: python-3.x

As I mentioned in the title, how can I subtract the specified date from today's date? I wrote a code like below, I would appreciate if you help

```
visa = input("Enter your visa note: ")
final = input("Enter your final grade: ")
result = (float(visa)*0.3) + (float(final)*0.7)
print("Your average {0} ".format(result))
if result>=50:
 print("You passed the class")
else:
 print('Failed from class')
import datetime
x = datetime.datetime.now()
date = (2025, 2, 18) # specified date
st = (f'Exam date: ({date}')
print(f'days left to retake the exam: {}') # I didn't know what to put in the curly brackets.
print(f'Today's date: {x}')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Is the code before `import datetime` relevant for your question?

Comment: Yup. What I want is, if the guy doesn't pass the exam, I want him to tell me the time remaining to retake the exam. But if the guy passed the exam I want him not to tell the remaining time

Comment: 1. Then your indentation seems to be off. The date calculation is outside of the `if`-`else` block. But I actually wanted to suggest 2. that you create a minimal example for your technical question "How can I subtract the specified date from today's date".

Answer (score 0):

you can just subtract it like this it seems to work

```
from datetime import datetime

def days_between(d1, d2):
    d1 = datetime.strptime(d1, "%Y-%m-%d")
    d2 = datetime.strptime(d2, "%Y-%m-%d")
    return abs((d2 - d1).days)


print(days_between('2021-08-03','2022-08-03'))
```

Comment: yes it worked but is there a chance we can do something like, can we ask it to automatically capture the day instead of typing it ourselves?

Comment: `d1` in this answer can also be `x = datetime.datetime.now()` from your question.

Comment: hmm, I just tested the code but it's going wrong somewhere. Even though the class has passed, the function is printing again on the screen, how can I stop this? I don't want this function to work if the average is 50 or equal to 50